# AngularJS routing is sometimes not working on IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

I`m experiencing some strange issue:
I have angular website with simple routing. Everything works fine on Chrome, Safari and FF.

In IE10 it sometimes works and sometimes not. When it doesn't it simply doesn't do anything. no error no network traffic.

It just changes the url in the address bar. even if I press 'enter' in the address bar nothing happens. Only F5 helps in this case.

The problem is just with one routing type ('mysite.com/#/cars/:id'), all other links and routes works fine. and it's always happened after going to the root page > click on some link > return to root and then try to click on the list with the problematic route.

I`m using latest stable version (1.0.7)

Thanks!!

Comment: I am having the same issue and the weirdness is that the hash changes and if you use the back / forward buttons THEN the UI updates / IE makes the network calls to get the templates / data as needed.  Going to be watching this closely and report back if I find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my issue, seemed to stem from kendoUI and angular not acting nicely.  When I clicked on a node in the treeview I was setting the window.location.href and that didn't work in IE, however using jQuery to get the anchor tag and calling the click event handler seems to have gotten me around whatever limitation was specific to IE.

Here is my code before:

```
window.location.href = "#/folder/" + idFolder
```

and after this is what it looks like:

```
$("a[href='#/folder/" + idFolder + "']").click();
```

I have not given [angular-kendo](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo) a try, but that is going to be my next step as I do not like the solution I had to put in place.

Hoping this helps you find a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your IE compatibility level to set to IE10. Sometimes if its in lower than IE10 we got more issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  This is an ng-route bug for < IE11.

It is not a good practice to use JQuery in order to fix AngularJS routes.  IE8 and above bug fix is available here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

This should solve your issue.
Good luck!

Comment: Nothing on that page relating to ng-route, what exactly is the fix?